# How to get child views of a ViewGroup in Android?

Tags: android, view, android-webview, viewgroup

I have to get child views of WebView. For some text manipulations, I wonder if there is a way to set attributes of child views, for example:

```
View[] childs = webView.getChilds;
View ch = childs[0];
ch.setText("manipulated text");
```

Answer (score 7):

WebView has methods `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt(int index)`. You can try to use these methods, but better solution is Bixi's one.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use findViewById ?

```
TextView subElement = (TextView) webview.findViewById(R.id.subelement);
subElement.setText("Oh Hi");
```

If you really want to iterate over the child, you can also use [ViewGroup::getChildAt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) and [ViewGroup::getChildCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount%28%29)

Comment: I don't know about inner views, can you write some applied code? Thanks.

Comment: All you need is in my post, if you need code example : I strongly suggest you to read the Android Training pages : http://developer.android.com/training/index.html because it's some very basic android methods

Comment: **findViewById()** Is exacting to resources